# How can I achieve this look in Blender?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I tried sculpting a cylinder but it wont work. I also tried bump and normal mapping but I can`t figure it out.

Comment: hello, noise and bumps should work, you could also use a Displace modifier but it means a subdivided mesh, but if you want to stick to what we see, sculpt is probably the best solution, could you please show your attempt (with the Node Shader)?

Comment: Wait so you can sculpt it because when I tried it didn`t do anything. @moonboots

Comment: it's hard to tell why you failed, did you at least subdivided your cylinder (vertically)

Answer (score 3):

The lightest solution (as it doesn't need any subdivision) would be to fake all the 3D bumps with a *Noise Texture* plugged into a *Bump* node. Other solutions would be to subdivide your cylinder and give it a *Displace* modifier or even to sculpt it. Also decrease the *Roughness* value and increase the *Specular*.

[image]